# Imbalanced binary classification results discussion

Tags: classification, cross-validation, modeling, scikit-learn, keras

Hello I'm wondering how do you consider these result For binary classification with class imbalance.(84% to 16).

Accuracy 96 Precision 94 Recall 80 F1 86 Roc_auc 98

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/1352